# Connecting Models from different Apps - Django

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-models, orm

Given that I have 4 models:

- `Project`
- `User` (from django.contrib.auth.models)
- `Sentence`
- `Translation`

My django project directories are structured as such:

```
 \myprojname
     \project
         models.py
     \data
         models.py
```

The `User` model is independent of the `Projects` and `Sentences` models but it is linked to the `Projects` model through the ForeignKey:

`myprojname/projects/models.py` looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Project(models.Model):
    project_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    # Admin user for the particular *Project* object.
    # Have the rights to write to the *Sentence* model.
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # Worker users that only have write access to the *Translation model.
    workers = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
```

`myprojname/data/models.py` looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Sentence(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    translations = models.ManyToManyField('Translation', blank=True)

class Translation(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    translator = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Now the `Project` model isn't connected to the `Sentence` model.

I've tried connecting it with relative imports, i.e. in `myprojname/projects/models.py`, I did:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ..data import Sentence

class Project(models.Model):
    # ...
    sentences = models.ForeignKey(Sentence)
```

but it returned a `ValueError` in `Python2.7`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper

    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/alvas/data-project/myprojname/project/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..data import Sentence
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

And in `Python3`, the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise

    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/alvas/data-project/myprojname/project/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..data import Sentence
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

And when I tried to do a non-relative import in `Python3`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myprojname.data import Sentence

class Project(models.Model):
    # ...
    sentences = models.ForeignKey(Sentence)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run

    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/payer/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/alvas/data-project/myprojname/project/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from myprojname.data import Sentence
ImportError: No module named 'myprojname.data'
```

**How do I connect the models from different apps?**

---

## Edited

When I used `from data import Sentence` in `myprojname.project.models.py`, it throws an `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/statnlp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/statnlp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/statnlp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/statnlp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/statnlp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/statnlp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/statnlp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/statnlp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/alvas/.virtualenvs/statnlp/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/alvas/data-project/myprojname/project/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from data import Sentence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sentence'
```

Comment: One question, why relative imports when you can do from data.models import Sentence?

Comment: And non-relative import would be from data.models import Sentence instead of from myprojname.data import Sentence

Comment: Oh sorry you had to do from data.models import Sentence, my mistake.

Comment: Ah great! Now that works `from data.models import Sentence` !! Any idea what allows Django to be different from normal python such that it can do imports without being in the right directory or relative imports?

Comment: Nothing. Django is not in any way different from "normal Python" here.

Comment: Ah @DanielRoseman, silly me, it's because `manage.py` is ran at the `myprojname` directory so it has access to models in the subdirectories, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import should be `from data.models import Sentence` instead of  `from myprojname.data import Sentence`.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh!!! But any idea what allows Django to be different from normal python such that it can do imports without being in the right directory or relative imports?

Comment: I am not entirely sure in this regards.